# instance name as variable

Tags: javascript, object

I have searched this site and also googled but can't seem to find the answer.

I need to create object instances dynamically where the instance name is provided as variable, so rather than access the object properties using:

```
var n = 'abcd';

eval('var '+n+' = new myinst();');

abcd.property = value;
```

I need to access using a variable:

```
['abcd'].property = value;
```

But this does not appear to work - what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `eval` in that way. You can easily assign "dynamic" variables to some base object instead:

```
var baseObj = {};
var n = 'abcd';

baseObj[n] = new myinst();
baseObj[n].property = value;
```

This gives you full control over the variable, including the ability to `delete` it,

```
delete baseObj[n];
```

Or check if it exists,

```
n in baseObj;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's easy when you know how :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do "variable variables" using the array notation, but you need to provide a context for it. In the global scope, that would be the `window`:

```
var foo = 'bar';
window[foo] = new myinst();
window[foo].property = 'baz';
alert(bar.property);
```

Substitute `window` for whatever other scope a variable variable should live in. Variable variables are really an anti-pattern that shouldn't be used though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a global you can use:

```
var n = 'abcd';
window[ n ] = new myInst();
window[ n ].property = value;
```